# How to save generated pdf in project directory structure in src/main/resources. . in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pdf-generation

```
       **Please Guide me how to save the generated pdf in src/main/resources 
        folder .**



        @Component
        public class PdfGenaratorUtil {
        @Autowired
        private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

        public String createPdf(String templateName, Map map)
            throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull(templateName, "The templateName can not be null");
        Context ctx = new Context();
        if (map != null) {
            Iterator> itMap = map.entrySet().iterator();
            while (itMap.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = itMap.next();
                ctx.setVariable(pair.getKey().toString(), pair.getValue());
            }
        }
         String processedHtml = templateEngine.process(templateName, ctx);
         FileOutputStream os = null;
         String fileName = "POLIST ";
         try {
            final File outputFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".pdf",
                    new File("C:\\Users\\ES001\\Desktop\\")); // Here I am 
             saving in direct path
            os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
            renderer.setDocumentFromString(processedHtml);
            renderer.layout();
            renderer.createPDF(os, false);
            renderer.finishPDF();
            System.out.println("PDF created successfully");
            return outputFile.toString();
            } finally {
            if (os != null) {
                try {
                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException e) { 
                }
             }
            }
           }
         }
```

Comment: Saving to src/main/resources does not make sense unless done by a tool to update project resources, and you can always create such a tool to either assume the current path to be the project path or to accept that path as parameter.

Comment: how can i get that path? I already have a folder in that. I want to use that folder to store my pdf file.

Comment: If it is a constant path in your environments, simply use its absolute path. Otherwise, if the program's current working directory is the project path, simply use src/main/resources. Otherwise, use command line parameters or configuration file settings injected into your been.